# Best way to start multiple "screen" scripts after restart? (centos)

Tags: centos, gnu-screen, init-script, init, init.d

We are using centos.
As soon as the server is restarted and the OS is fully loaded, we would like to have a certain user ("foo") start three or four scripts with screen.

For example,

`screen -d -m -S script1 forever -o script1.log -e script1.log -l script1.log -c php /path/to/script1.php`

What's the best way to achieve this using CentOS?
I would prefer to avoid having to dig into init.d too much.

Using systemd, I try to inspect the service ("notify") and see this:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/notify@.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-03-20 15:08:04 EDT; 14s ago
  Process: 1690 ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S notify -X quit (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 941 ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S notify forever -o notifyout.log -e notifyerr.log -l notifyforever.log -c php /path/to/script/notify.php (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 946 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Why is it getting stopped?  How can I begin to debug this?

Comment: "We are using centos." which version?  Also, why the aversion to starting these scripts using the init system, are there requirements leading you to use screen rather than your system's init setup or another process manager

Comment: apologies, I hit enter too fast. Just updated my comment with a more sensible question :D

Comment: @StevenD we are using CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core).  I like the idea of using 'screen' because if it seems to work well with the 'forever' tool, and if we need to restart them due to a modification, screen seems easier to keep checking.  However, I am completely open minded to choosing the approach that works best.

Comment: Is this the forever program you are referring to? https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: Yep.  Forever will monitor the script and restart if it crashes.  It will also send all the output (stdout and stderr) to log files.

Comment: Read the answer more carefully: use `-D` instead of `-d`. With the former, screen won't fork, matching the "Type=simple" directive. With the latter, it will, and the parent exits cleanly (status=0) - systemd would need to be told it's a "Type=forking" service to use that, but there's no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is CentOS 7, you should use a systemd service to start the service.  You can even have it run inside a screen.  From the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen#Autostart_with_systemd):

Create a file: `/etc/systemd/system/screen@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=screen
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=%i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -DmS autoscreen
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S autoscreen -X quit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable it with `systemctl enable screen@USERNAME.service`  If you don't plan on making it so it can be run under any user, you can get rid of the @ in the filename, and the @USERNAME in the unit name when enabling it, and hard-code the user in the unit file.

Comment: Thanks... Updated my post with some additional debugging info

Answer (score 0):

I edited `/etc/rc.local` and added this

`/etc/init.d/start_bg_scripts`

Then I added `/etc/init.d/start_bg_scripts`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S script1 forever --minUptime 1 --spinSleepTime 1 -o script1out.log -e script1err.log -l script1forever.log -c php /path/to/script.php
```

The --minUptime 1 and --spinSleepTime 1 means that they keep trying to reconnect until the rest of the system services (e.g. mysqld) become available